# From Lead in a small team, to Senior in a large tech team

Tags: career-development, career-switch, leadership, seniority

The company that i'm currently working for is in the business the last 25 years, is heavily sales- and marketing-based although relying on web applications, is quite successful, however with little appreciation for the Tech team who was considered mostly as Support.

1.5 years ago the company hired a new CIO, who came with a lot of energy, breakthrough ideas and a new vision for the Tech department. Last week was his last week in the company, as he and the President had many differences over time, and now this role will be filled internally by a more conservative, non-web related executive. This shows to me that there's no interest in innovation, but rather keep things stable and support the "bread-makers" of the company.

My professional career started 4.5 years ago. I have been working in this company for 3.5 years. I joined as a Front end developer, and quickly grew to lead a small team (2) of front end developers (front end team size is 3). I don't have the Lead title yet, as the company kept postponing it saying that I wasn't ready and that we have to work on it and "groom" me in becoming one. Regardless, I've been leading the team's efforts for the last 1 year having full responsibility in my area of knowledge.

Now, i've been approached by a great tech company (think Ebay in this specific country) for the second time in 1 year, for a Senior front end role, with an approximate 15% increase of my salary. It is a position with responsibilities, where I can put my leadership skills that I have acquired so far in use. That company has a clear career path, where a developer after the senior level can grow to the Lead or Principal engineer level. The tech team size is much larger, with more levels, such as Engineer 1 & 2, Senior 1 & 2, where 2 means more responsibilities.

Some family members believe that I should stay in my current position because I don't have enough people-skills in order to have a good career progress in another, bigger tech company where the competition is tougher, and that I should stay here for 1-2 more years till I become more "ready".

On the other hand I feel that there's no point staying in a company where there's no clear career path or progress, where the Sales & Marketing teams are considered heroes and Tech is mostly support.

**Is there real value staying in a company only because I have a good position, which gives me the necessary people-skills to be more competent in the next job, rather than going with a tech company that has a better career growth path, where I'll be less of a lead and more hands-on code, but still involved in decision making, and with the potential of becoming a lead or principal engineer in the future?**

Comment: We can't answer "what should I do?" questions. Everything in your question depends on your own view of your worth and skills, and we're not party to that. VTC, sorry.

Comment: I'd love to offer an answer but you've basically made the decision yourself!   To summarise your family are saying "Stay in place so you can get experience for a promotion!" when actually, you have the promotion offer already... They're crazy, you should go for a new company.

Comment: I've re-worded my question, asking for help to make the right decision based on the information that I've provided, not asking for the right decision itself.

Comment: @Manos It's still too broad. "Is there a way to help me decide..." you could use a magic 8 ball... you could ask your family/relatives/friends. you could do a billion things. :/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I changed my question to be more specific.

Comment: Question looks better to me. Anyway, I feel that it bottles down to a single thing. "do you want to improve yourself or are you happy with where you currently stand" In your current company you will most likely gain a salary based on inflation and possibly more. However, by switching jobs every 4-ish years, you can gain new experiences, gain new challenges. Personally I'd ALWAYS go for newer experiences. However this is bound by the other company's location, your family's location and how much you like your current co-workers. As you'll leave things behind, but certainly can gain much more.